# Does LoadLibrary return NULL or an error code < 32 on failure?

Tags: winapi

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx) states

> If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the module.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is `NULL`. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.

while [Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/142814/en-us#appliesto) has a list of return values less than 32 that indicate an error

> The API function `LoadLibrary` loads a DLL and returns either a handle or an error code. If the return value is less than 32, it indicates one of the errors listed below. A return value greater than or equal to 32 indicates success and you should call the `FreeLibrary` function to unload the library.

The second article was last reviewed in 2003 and explicitly applies to Visual Basic 4.0.

What is correct? `LoadLibrary` returning `!= 0` or `>= 32` for success? Or are both correct and I am missing some hint for a Version difference or a VB specific Windows API wrapper that differs from the C style interface?

Comment: A quick test in C passing an invalid file name returns `NULL`, not `2` (File was not found) as listed in the VB documentation you linked.

Comment: @WeatherVane That proves nothing

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that is why I posted my observation as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you. Of course I did that sort of testing too prior to asking, but mentioning every try & error attempt to figure this out might have bloated the question.

Comment: @Weather: It's not even a helpful comment. You cannot deduce contractual guarantees from observations. Suggesting otherwise is fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- In 32 and 64 bit Windows, `LoadLibrary` returns `NULL` on failure.
- In 16 bit Windows `LoadLibrary` returns a value less than 32 to indicate failure.

[KB142814](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/142814/) clearly dates from the 16 bit Windows days, and if you look closely you will see a kb16bitonly keyword. I think it is safe to assume that you are not developing for 16 bit Windows anymore!

Some relevant articles from Raymond Chen on this matter:

- [What is the difference between HINSTANCE and HMODULE?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/14/155107.aspx)
- [What can I do with the HINSTANCE returned by the ShellExecute function?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/05/590749.aspx)

The modern day documentation for `LoadLibrary` is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx, that is the first link in your question. It says:

> **Return value**
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the module.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. I did notice the kb16bitonly tag, but "Applies To: [...]. Microsoft Visual Basic 4.0 32-Bit Enterprise Edition [...]" lead me astray again.

Comment: @die_hoernse VB4 could produce both 16 and 32 bit outputs, IIRC. It straddled the transition.