# @ Operator usage when mapping method entry points

Tags: delphi, dll

When dynamically loading a DLL where `DoSomething` is a method type variable we can do

```
 DoSomething:= GetProcAddress(MyDLLHandle ,'DoSomething');
```

or

```
 @DoSomething:= GetProcAddress(MyDLLHandle ,'DoSomething');
```

Both of these seem to behave identically in modern versions of Delphi.  My question is - has the `@` operator always been optional and, if not, in which version of Delphi did it become optional?

The documentation states that `@`, when used with routine (function/procedure) types returns the entry point of the function with type `Pointer`. When using the variable directly it naturally has whatever specific type it was declared with but also returns the entry point to the method.  `GetProcAddress` returns a `Pointer` so I'm assuming that the habit of including `@` when loading a DLL comes from a time when these mismatched types were not assignment compatible.  Is this the case?

Are there any reasonable arguments to prefer either of these styles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe that anything has changed since the original versions of Delphi.

The official header translation for `GetProcAddress` has a return type of `FARPROC` which is an alias to the untyped `Pointer` type. Because of this, you can put pretty much anything pointer-esque on the left hand side of the assignment statement, because type checking is suspended when one of the operands is `Pointer`.

On the other hand, consider this program:

```
var
  Proc: procedure;
  Ptr: Pointer;

begin
  Ptr := Proc;
end.
```

This fails to compile with:

> E2010 Incompatible types: 'Pointer' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'

The simple fix is to use the `@` operator:

```
var
  Proc: procedure;
  Ptr: Pointer;

begin
  Ptr := @Proc;
end.
```

It is certainly the case that many Delphi examples use:

```
@Proc := GetProcAddress(...);
```

rather than

```
Proc := GetProcAddress(...);
```

I rather suspect that there is nothing deep here. Just a case of a choice made by the author of one of the first online articles on the subject propagating throughout history with no good reason. Which reminds me of the terrible [Rosetta code example](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Call_a_function_in_a_shared_library#Dynamic_loading) of dynamic loading that tests whether an `HMODULE` is greater than 32, an erroneous check that can be seen in Stack Overflow questions on a weekly basis!

Should you use `@` in these circumstances or not? In my view you should not. It doesn't make much difference, and given that why bother with a needless piece of punctuation?

There is one other scenario that I know where you need to use `@`, and in that case you actually need `@@`. Consider the following program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  Proc: procedure;
  Ptr: Pointer;

begin
  Ptr := @Proc;
  Writeln(Format('%p', [Ptr]));
  Ptr := @@Proc;
  Writeln(Format('%p', [Ptr]));
  Readln;
end.
```

**Output**

```
00000000
00423EBC
```

The first assignment gets the value held in the `Proc` variable, which because it is a default initialised global, is zero. The second assignment gets the address of the `Proc` variable. And for that you need `@@`. It's pretty unusual to need this much indirection, but it tends to crop up when writing code related to dynamic linking.

Comment: Yes, assignment the other way it is obviously necessary.  My feeling that this was a monkey-see monkey-do thing.  I personally write my imports without the extraneous `@` but couldn't produce a satisfying answer when asked this today as to why so many other import boilerplates do use it.

Comment: Monkey see monkey do is a cute way of putting it

Comment: I wonder where that magic number 32 comes from. AFAIK, LoadLibrary either returns NULL or a valid handle. And yes, I have seen it more often too.

Comment: @rudy it comes from the 32 bit version of LoadLibrary. Values less than 32 were error codes IIRC. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30862919/505088

Comment: @David: Yes, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862874/does-loadlibrary-return-null-or-an-error-code-32-on-failure. Can't follow the link to MS support anymore, though.

Comment: Hmmm... according to your own answer, it was the 16 bit version that returned a value < 32 as error code.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant